# Upgrade from .net 4.0 to 4.5.1 breaks WCF

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5

I am working with windows server 2008 r2 running iis 7.5.  My WCF service was running on framework 4.0.  32-bit app running integrated pipeline.

Service is in a virtual directory with Annonymous and Windows Authentication enabled.  My configuration looks like:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyWebservice.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyWebservice.MyServiceBehavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="MyWebservice.IMyService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyWebservice.MyServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

With framework 4.0 everything worked fine.  After upgrading to framework 4.5.1 when I connect with the WCF Test Client from an account that is on the domain, I get the following exception:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate, NTLM'.

This error is profoundly un-helpful since everything was configured correctly and working fine in .net 4.0.  I went as far as trying to uninstall the wcf service, rebuilding it and targeting framework 4.5.1 (everything works on my dev machine) then re-deloying a new msi with the 4.5.1 targeted build.  The most maddening thing is the first request to the service always works, every request after that returns the above error.  Any ideas out there?

**Additional Info**

Even with a fresh install of windows 2008 r2 with all updates installed and only framework 4.5.1 and the requisite IIS components installed (no other apps other than virus scanner installed) this error still comes up.

**Edit #2**

Also added SPNs as per scenario #1

> http://mingkunsnotes.blogspot.ca/2010/01/iis-windows-integrated-authentication.html

No Luck.

**Edit #3**

My site is running on a different port than 80, say 888.  I tried the following spns:

```
setspn -A HTTP/myServerName myServerName
setspn -A HTTP/myServerName.company.com myServerName
```

When that didn't work, I deleted those SPNs and tried:

```
setspn -A HTTP/myServerName:888 myServerName
setspn -A HTTP/myServerName.company.com:888 myServerName
```

That did not work either.  Also tried enabling and disabling kernel-mode authentication and making Negotiate-Kerberos the only provider.  Nothing works.

**Edit #4**

Tried setting useAppPoolCredentials = true.  Nope.

Comment: Have you tired configuring iis as per https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87381844-c0e3-48db-862f-0ed6969c6aed/net-451-potential-kerberos-related-bugchange-in-wcf-causing-http-request-is-unauthorized-with?forum=wcf

Comment: Yes.  I don't think the service would work on the first request and then fail on subsequent ones unless the windows authentication was working to some extent.  I have gone as far as using wireshark to confirm that authentication data is being sent, although its using something called GSS-API which I'm not sure what that is and why it's failing at the moment.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/05/29/kerberos-authentication-problems-service-principal-name-spn-issues-part-1.aspx